# Picture not showing bottle.py

Tags: python, html, bottle

My picture isnt showing, I tryed copying code and that didnt work. I want to be able to do this, what am i doing wrong?

my code

```
from bottle import route, run,Response,template
from bottle import *
import socket
temp=open("ht","r")
html1=temp.read()
temp=open("html2","r")
html2=temp.read()

@route("/")
  def route1():

     return html1



 run(host=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), port=8080, debug=True)
```

in html1

```
  <img src="C:\Users\radbo\Desktop\discord bots\drago\chat\RUn\Servers\Turtle.png" width=290 length=100>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `template` function to call your HTML so it is cached, then create a static path to your image file.

```
from bottle import route, run, response, request, template, static_file, get

@route("/")
def route1():
    #this should be your full filename, like index.html
    return template('ht')     

@get('/static/<filepath:path>')
def _shared(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, 'C:\Users\radbo\Desktop\discord bots\drago\chat\RUn\Servers' )

run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Then you can just do:

```
<img src="\static\Turtle.png" width=290 length=100>
```